# Getting can't serialize access exception for task in SCDF

Tags: oracle11g, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are using SCDF 1.2.3.RELEASE (Local Server) for calling different task created using spring cloud task 1.2.2.RELEASE which is internally using batch jobs for the actual job. Both of these SCDF and the task are using the same Oracle DB.
When we trigger a task from already registered on SCDF, sometimes we can see the start time for that task but the overall initialization of the task gets failed with the following error

```
2018-02-28 11:23:50.286 ERROR 2719 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               
: Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.vmware.usage.report.UsageETLBatchApplication.main(UsageETLBatchApplication.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
    Caused by: org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
    ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:267)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:937)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:942)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:115)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:883)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Please find the properties file for the SCDF server below:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:9000/eureka/
spring.application.name=SpringCloudDataFlowServer


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<db>
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver


spring.cloud.deployer.local.deleteFilesOnExit=false
spring.cloud.deployer.local.javaOpts=-Xms256M -Xmx1G

spring.zipkin.baseUrl=http://localhost:8012/
spring.zipkin.urlSuffix=api/zipkin_trace/spans
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=1.0
```

Please find the properties file of the task below:

```
spring.application.name=SpringCloudTask
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.task=DEBUG

spring.oracle.datasource.url =jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<db>
spring.oracle.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.oracle.datasource.password=PASSWORD
spring.oracle.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.data.mongodb.host=HOST
spring.data.mongodb.port=PORT
spring.data.mongodb.database=DATABASE
spring.data.mongodb.username=USERNAME
spring.data.mongodb.password=PASSWORD

spring.zipkin.baseUrl=http://localhost:8012/
spring.zipkin.urlSuffix=api/zipkin_trace/spans
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=1.0

#other task-specific properties
```

Also, we are creating the required database structure by default before running the SCDF server as some of our environments may not have the access to services to create the tables. Please find the Database script below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xajuUz-7IBtdKyGWuxmQavqhYEPY1pt_/view?usp=sharing

Please let us know how can we solve this "can't serialize access for this transaction" exception

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a Spring Batch issue (not a Spring Cloud Task one).   Try changing the transaction isolation level to `ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ`.

Comment: But we are getting this error when Spring cloud task tries to insert the data into  BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE which it does on it own. How can we solve this

Comment: Do you have any example for this?

Comment: As far as I know, the default isolation of Oracle is always ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ.

Comment: The default for Spring Batch is `ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE`